# Irreducibility of $x^m-g(y)$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $g(y)\in \mathbb{C}[y]$, $ m\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2}$. Are there some results on the irreducibility of $x^m-g(y)$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Comment: It is irreducible if and only if $g$ is not a $p$-th power for every prime divisor $p \mid m$. This is a special case of the Vahlen-Capelli theorem, which for an arbitrary field $F$ precisely determines the irreducible binomials $x^m-a \in F[x]$.